# jQuery Drag only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I don't want to use the jQuery UI, so I tried to make a jQuery Drag Script on my own.

This is basically my code for horizontal Dragging:

```
var down = false;

$('#itemToMove').mousedown(function(e){
    down = true;
    left = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    down = false;
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(down){
        var X = event.pageX - left;
        $('#itemToMove').css({
            left: X
        });
    }
});
```

I works just awesome in Chrome, but doesn't in other browsers (tried KHTML, Trident and Gecko).
Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Is left a global variable? in this snippet it is not defined. Can you not use the jQuery draggable plugin?

Comment: Seems you use both `e` and `event` for the event object?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. I replaced all e with event and now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty damn sure that if you put an alert("") inside your mousedown event handler, it will never fire. That's because by the time you try to bind the event handler to the object's mousedown event, the object (your div) does not exist yet. Try wrapping your entire code block in

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    // Your code here
    });

Something like this:

```
    var down = false;
    var left = 0;

    $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $('#itemToMove').mousedown(function(e)
            {
            down = true;
            left = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            });

        $(document).mouseup(function()
            {
            down = false;
            });

        $(document).mousemove(function(e)
            {
            if(down)
                {
                var X = e.pageX - left;
                $('#itemToMove').css(
                    {
                    left: X
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Hope it helps :]

Added: Also, make sure you skim through this document: http://api.jquery.com/ready, especially the following part:

> Note: Please make sure that all stylesheets are included before your scripts (especially 
>   those that call the ready function). Doing so will make sure that all element properties are correctly defined before jQuery code begins executing. Failure to do this will cause sporadic problems, especially on WebKit-based browsers such as Safari.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did put the script into the ready function. The Stylesheets and the DOM rendered before the actual JavaScript.

Comment: Well, if you look carefully, I actually renamed your event to e before posting, just forgot to mention it :] Cheers